# Match number from a Javascript array to a math variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Please understand I'm not at all a Javascript Programmer so I'm stuck at the last step in a simple form calculator I'm trying to build. I'm able to load the form array values, find the highest value from each option but I want it to display the text instead of the value.

```
 //Set up an associative array 
 //The keys represent the cards type
 //We use this this array when the user selects a cards from the form
var cards_values = new Array();
cards_values["None"] = 0;
cards_values["Lemon"] = 5;
cards_values["Custard"] = 5;
cards_values["Fudge"] = 7;
cards_values["Mocha"] = 8;
cards_values["Raspberry"] = 10;
cards_values["Pineapple"] = 5;
cards_values["Dobash"] = 9;
cards_values["Mint"] = 5;
cards_values["Cherry"] = 5;
cards_values["Apricot"] = 8;
cards_values["Buttercream"] = 7;
cards_values["Chocolate Mousse"] = 12;



 //This function finds the cards price based on the 
 //drop down selection
function getCardValue() {
  var cardValue = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cardform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cardform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="cards"
  var selectedCard = theForm.elements["cards"];

  //set Card Price equal to value user chose
  //For example cards_values["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
  cardValue = cards_values[selectedCard.value];

  //finally we return cardValue
  return cardValue;
}

 //This function finds the cards price based on the 
 //drop down selection
function getCardValue1() {
  var cardValue1 = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cardform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cardform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="cards"
  var selectedCard = theForm.elements["cards1"];

  //set Card Price equal to value user chose
  //For example cards_values["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
  cardValue1 = cards_values[selectedCard.value];

  //finally we return cardValue
  return cardValue1;
}

 //This function finds the cards price based on the 
 //drop down selection
function getCardValue2() {
  var cardValue2 = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cardform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cardform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="cards"
  var selectedCard = theForm.elements["cards2"];

  //set Card Price equal to value user chose
  //For example cards_values["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
  cardValue2 = cards_values[selectedCard.value];

  //finally we return cardValue
  return cardValue2;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var highcardvalue = Math.max(getCardValue(), getCardValue1(), getCardValue2());


  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('highestcard');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "The highest card is " + highcardvalue;

}

function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('highestcard');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/golf153/vnS4D/3/)

I can't tell if I should rebuild using obj or if some other solution would work better.

Comment: [Don't use an `Array` there](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: There is no such thing as an associative array in javascript.  Either use an object (with string keys) or an array (with numeric keys).  It looks like you should be using an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yeah, lets go ahead and just remove half of that code..**

**edit:** found a bug in `getKeyXVal`, it would match the first selection whose value matched, which isn't a problem unless you have several of the same values with different keys (which you do), so if you were to select any combination of `lemon, custard, pineapple, mint, and cherry` lemon will always be listed as the highest card even when not selected. To fix this I added an array, `curSel`, which stores only the current selections and their values and added it to `highCard` instead of `cards_values`.

```
var cards_values = {
    None: 0,
    Lemon: 5,
    Custard: 5,
    Fudge: 7,
    Mocha: 8,
    Raspberry: 10,
    Pineapple: 5,
    Dobash: 9,
    Mint: 5,
    Cherry: 5,
    Apricot: 8,
    Buttercream: 7,
    'Chocolate Mousse': 12
},
    curSel = [];//store currently selected cards

Object.prototype.getKeyXVal = function (value) {
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (this[key] === value) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
};

function getCardValue() {
    cardValue = 0;//default card value
    curSel = [];//clear
    var theForm = document.forms.cardform,
        selectedCard = theForm.getElementsByTagName("select"),//get selects by tag
        biggest;//the biggest number.... EVER
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCard.length; i++) {//for each select
        sc = selectedCard[i].value;//current selections
        cardValue = cards_values[sc];//get values
        curSel[sc]=cardValue;//add current selections
        if (!biggest) { biggest=cardValue; }//initial biggest
        else if (cardValue > biggest) { biggest = cardValue; }//the largest biggest
    }
    return biggest;//return biggest
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var highcardvalue = getCardValue(),
        highCard = curSel.getKeyXVal(highcardvalue),
        divobj = document.getElementById('highestcard');
    divobj.style.display = 'block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "The highest card is " + highCard;
}

function hideTotal() {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('highestcard');
    divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

This way it goes by the `select` tags instead of direct `ID` of each `select`. It simply stores highest `select` value and returns it.

This will be much easier to manage and maintain.

[**made a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/5ZjbK/)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I planned to have unique values with my final (non-fruit based) data set keys. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an array as an object -- arrays take `integer` keys and have a length property.  Objects take `string` keys.

And though JavaScript objects are often called an associative array, they aren't.  Similar in many respects, but different in some important ones.

(The fact that arrays are built on top of objects means what you are doing *works* but it isn't right.)

```
var cards_values= {
 "None": 0,
 "Lemon": 5,
 "Custard": 7,
 "Fudge": 7
 "Mocha": 8,
 "Raspberry": 10,
 "Pineapple": 5,
 "Dobash": 9,
 "Mint": 5,
 "Cherry": 5,
 "Apricot": 8,
 "Buttercream": 7,
 "Chocolate Mousse": 12
};
```